# Ada OOP "generic" types for abstract type

Tags: oop, pointers, generics, ada, memory-address

What I want to do is make a type that, among other things, controls values that other parts of the code pass to it. This is part of a menu system, and would extend an abstract type and itself be abstract. What I would like to do is store an access. Simple enough.

```
type Adjuster is abstract new Menu_Item with record
    --other fields
    Value : access Integer;
end record;
```

Question is, how can I make this extendable to other types? I'd prefer that to having to define Integer_Adjuster, Float_Adjuster, etc. I kinda thought of using generics:

```
generic
    type T;
    type T_Access is access T;
type Adjuster is abstract new Menu_Item with record
    --other fields
    Value : T_Access;
end record;
```

But this tells me that there's a semicolon missing on the "type Adjuster..." line, presumably because Ada/Gnat can't figure out whether the line is declaring a type that should be included in the generic portion or this is the type the generic portion should be applied to. I think the only way to do this would be to actually make an Adjuster package and make that generic (but I'd rather not...).

I also toyed with the idea storing an Address rather than an Access, since Ada doesn't care what kind of Address it is:

```
type Adjuster is abstract new Menu_Item with record
    --other fields
    Value : System.Address
end record;
```

But first of all I don't know enough about Addresses to determine whether this will work or *how* it would work (do you assign to Value.all..?) and second, being able to store a *[shrugs shoulders]* really feels like the kind of thing that Ada is *designed to not be able to do*.

I'm kinda out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ada does not provide generic types. Packages are Ada's unit of encapsulation, not types. Try creating a generic package.

Comment: @JimRogers Thanks for the comment. It doesn't necessarily need to be a generic type or even make use of generics at all. I'd prefer not to make a dedicated package for this type if there's some other way to maybe set up the type so that it can reference data of different types.

Comment: Generic parameters can only passed to generic units. You might try creating a tagged type as the root of an inheritance tree in one package, and provide a generic package for extending that type and its associated methods. The base package should contain one or more dispatching procedures or functions.

Comment: Consider reexamining that mindset. Would you be equally reluctant to declare a class in Java or C++? Packages can be quite lightweight, they don't need to add a pair of files to your project. They can even be declared local to a single procedure if that is appropriate, i.e. if there is no need to expose them elsewhere. They ARE the unit of encapsulation as Jim says. So a generic package exposing a type and its methods is an appropriate solution.

Comment: @JimRogers I suppose that essentially amounts to declaring a type for each of int, float, etc. Brian brings up a good point about classes in Java and C++, too. Thanks, I guess I'll make a package around it.

Answer (score 3):

You might get what you want, by making the type you want to extend `tagged`.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't notice that base type is not declared as tagged.